# I don't want to fetch child dependency if I didn't joined it in query

Tags: rest, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

These are my POJOs

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="schedules")
public class Schedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="source_dep_time")
    private Time sourceDepTime;
    
    @Column(name="dest_arr_time")
    private Time destArrTime;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="plane_id")
    private Plane plane;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="source_id")
    private Airport source;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="destination_id")
    private Airport destination;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="schedule", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<Fare> fare;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="fare")
public class Fare {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="fare")
    private double fare;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="class_id")
    private Classes classType;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name="schedule_id")
    private Schedule schedule;
```

and here is my query

```java
public interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation, Integer> {

    @Query("from Reservation r join fetch r.ticket t join fetch r.payment join t.schedule sc join fetch sc.source join fetch sc.destination join fetch sc.plane pl " +
            "join fetch pl.airline join fetch r.passengers p join fetch p.seat s join s.classes where t.pnr = ?1")
    Reservation getReservationDetails(int pnr);
}
```

Problem is that I am not joining the fare Column of Schedule class still in result I'm getting fare data and it's dependency data and I don't want to fetch fare in this situation but I want that if I declare JOIN or JOIN FETCH in query then it should give me that data.

I also tried only JOIN instead of JOIN FETCH, but that didn't worked too.

Generated SQL is (manually formatted):

```sql
select reservatio0_.id as id1_8_0_, ticket1_.id as id1_11_1_, payment2_.id as id1_5_2_, schedule3_.id as id1_9_3_, airport4_.id as id1_1_4_, airport5_.id as id1_1_5_, plane6_.id as id1_7_6_, airline7_.id as id1_0_7_, passengers8_.id as id1_4_8_, seat9_.id as id1_10_9_, classes10_.id as id1_2_10_, reservatio0_.journey_date as journey_2_8_0_, reservatio0_.payment_id as payment_4_8_0_, reservatio0_.res_date_time as res_date3_8_0_, reservatio0_.ticket_id as ticket_i5_8_0_, ticket1_.pnr as pnr2_11_1_, ticket1_.schedule_id as schedule3_11_1_, payment2_.amount_paid as amount_p2_5_2_, schedule3_.dest_arr_time as dest_arr2_9_3_, schedule3_.destination_id as destinat4_9_3_, schedule3_.plane_id as plane_id5_9_3_, schedule3_.source_id as source_i6_9_3_, schedule3_.source_dep_time as source_d3_9_3_, airport4_.city as city2_1_4_, airport4_.city_code as city_cod3_1_4_, airport5_.city as city2_1_5_, airport5_.city_code as city_cod3_1_5_, plane6_.airline_id as airline_3_7_6_, plane6_.plane_no as plane_no2_7_6_, airline7_.name as name2_0_7_, passengers8_.age as age2_4_8_, passengers8_.gender as gender3_4_8_, passengers8_.name as name4_4_8_, passengers8_.phone as phone5_4_8_, passengers8_.seat_id as seat_id6_4_8_, passengers8_.reservation_id as reservat7_4_0__, passengers8_.id as id1_4_0__, seat9_.class_id as class_id3_10_9_, seat9_.seat_no as seat_no2_10_9_, classes10_.type as type2_2_10_ 
from reservations reservatio0_ 
inner join tickets ticket1_ on reservatio0_.ticket_id=ticket1_.id 
inner join payments payment2_ on reservatio0_.payment_id=payment2_.id 
inner join schedules schedule3_ on ticket1_.schedule_id=schedule3_.id 
inner join airports airport4_ on schedule3_.source_id=airport4_.id 
inner join airports airport5_ on schedule3_.destination_id=airport5_.id 
inner join planes plane6_ on schedule3_.plane_id=plane6_.id 
inner join airlines airline7_ on plane6_.airline_id=airline7_.id 
inner join passengers passengers8_ on reservatio0_.id=passengers8_.reservation_id 
inner join seats seat9_ on passengers8_.seat_id=seat9_.id 
inner join classes classes10_ on seat9_.class_id=classes10_.id where ticket1_.pnr=?
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? That Hibernate (I assume) fetches the `Fare` when you don't want it to? Or that it doesn't fetch it, when you want it to?

Could you add the SQL that is generated, presumely including the Fare data? And the second query where you include the join fetch but Fare is not fetched?

Also if you could remove all the cruft that is irrelevant to the problem, like the extra joins and relationships that would make analysing this much easier.

Comment: Actually Fare is getting fetched in both situations either I apply JOIN / JOIN FETCH or not. I can stop it by adding `@JsonBackReference` or `@JsonIgnoreProperties` but then it doesn't fetch even after using JOIN / JOIN FETCH. I want to fetch in one situation and don't want to fetch in other situation. The thing is I'm displaying data in Json and I think JSON is triggering that fetchings.

Comment: what you posted is not the SQL generated by the queries, it is the schema generated from your mapping.

Comment: @JensSchauder sorry for not understanding. Now I have edited that thing

Comment: It doesn't seem to fetch fares. How do you determine that it fetches fares?

Comment: @JensSchauder Actually it adds two more queries below this `Hibernate: select fare0_.schedule_id as schedule4_3_0_, fare0_.id as id1_3_0_, fare0_.id as id1_3_1_, fare0_.class_id as class_id3_3_1_, fare0_.fare as fare2_3_1_, fare0_.schedule_id as schedule4_3_1_ from fare fare0_ where fare0_.schedule_id=?
Hibernate: select classes0_.id as id1_2_0_, classes0_.type as type2_2_0_ from classes classes0_ where classes0_.id=?` These queries are automatically appears. I think it is generating because i'm using **spring-data-rest**. But still it is a problem,

Comment: What do you mean by "I think it is generating because i'm using spring-data-rest?

Up to know you where claiming JPA is eager fetching data which it shouldn't. Now you are saying spring-data-rest is triggering lazy loading, which is a completely different question.

Please clarify: What code is triggering execution of which SQL statements and why you think that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Actually I'm creating REST api using spring-data-jpa and spring-data-rest and displaying results on browser in json format. I have written these codes but I'm not getting the desired output. I have tried different approaches but didn't work. Either it's hidden in all scenarios or displays every time.